# node.js buffer toString default utf8 but i want no encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, tostring

```
var iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;

var UtfToEuckr = new iconv('utf-8', 'euckr');

var result = UtfToEuckr.convert('한글');

var str = result.toString();  <- default convert utf8

str is UTF-8 string
```

i wanna no encoding to string
want result : `str is euckr string`

please, tell me know how..

thank for reading

Answer (score 0):

you always have some encoding, you should either try "ascii" or "binary" (whichever you mean in your situation)

Comment: mysql charset is euckr but nothing method

1) try mysql query 
2) all string encoding to UTF8 in node.js
3) i wanna euckr T_T

broken charset...

plz help me